# Needs to remove word from string and display both the removed word + remaining string, possible tuple?

Tags: python, string, tuples

I am a beginner coder so bear with me. I made up a question involving sandwiches names to practice my string manipulations and what they contain, I included an example in `sandwich.txt` below.

I made a short code to remove a certain string which in this case is `bacon` and I would like to return the value `[*what_I_removed*, *what_is_left_in_the_sandwich*]`

`sandwich.txt` contains:

```
BLTsandwich_bread_bacon_lettuce_tomato_bread
BREADsandwich_bread_bread_bread
HAMsandwich_bread_ham_bread
```

Here is my code:

```
import os
sandwich= open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'sandwich.txt'), 'r').readlines()

def NoBacon(sandwich):
    for x in range (0,len(sandwich)):
        if sandwich[x].rstrip('\n') in user_input:
            return [sandwich[x].rstrip('\n'),user_input.replace(sandwich[x].rstrip('\n')+'_','')]
            break

print (NoBacon(sandwich))
```

The output is:

```
['bacon', 'BLTsandwich_bread_lettuce_tomato_bread']
```

Does python have an easier way of doing this?

Comment: FYI, the thing you output is a list, not a tuple.

Comment: I am aware, I was inferring a possible easier method was with a tuple.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Got it.  Anyway, returning in list or tuple won't make a difference unless you want to do something else with the output later and mutability matters.  But in terms of what you're trying to achieve, have you looked at the replace() method in the string library?  very end of the page here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: What's in `user_input`?

Comment: You can use replace() method. See this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

Comment: @dlask it was originally just a string I used to test something and forgot to rename it, sorry for the confusion. Someone answered it so i will edit my code accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sandwich= ["BLTsandwich_bread_bacon_lettuce_tomato_bread",
"BREADsandwich_bread_bread_bread",
"HAMsandwich_bread_ham_bread"]

to_replace = ["bacon"]

def NoBacon(sandwich):
    replacements_made = []
    for line in sandwich:
        for word in to_replace:
            words_replaced = []
            if word in line:
                words_replaced.append(word)
                line = line.replace(word, "")
        replacements_made.append((words_replaced, line))
    return replacements_made

print (NoBacon(sandwich))
```

And here's the result

```
$ python mmmm_bacon.py 
[(['bacon'], 'BLTsandwich_bread__lettuce_tomato_bread'), ([], 'BREADsandwich_bread_bread_bread'), ([], 'HAMsandwich_bread_ham_bread')]
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out how to make this work with user input and how to remove the extra `_` characters.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solution is a lot more flexible.

Comment: Where did the line: `python mmmm_bacon.py` come from?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. That's the results of running a file I called `mmm_bacon.py` =P

Answer (score 1):

I know Im late but just another option !

```
import os
#sandwich= open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'sandwich.txt'), 'r').readlines()

sandwich = """
BLTsandwich_bread_bacon_lettuce_tomato_bread
BREADsandwich_bread_bread_bacon_bread_bacon
bacon_HAMsandwich_bacon_bread_ham_bread
Bacon_HAMsandwich_bacon_bread_ham_bread
"""

user_input = "bacon"

def NoBacon(sandwich):

    result = []
    length = len(user_input)
    lines = sandwich.strip().split('\n')

    for line in lines:
        cleaned_line = line.replace(user_input, '')
        if len(line) - len(cleaned_line) >= length:
            result.append([user_input, cleaned_line])


    return result

for k in (NoBacon(sandwich)):
    print k
```

Sample output For the above input string:

```
['bacon', 'BLTsandwich_bread__lettuce_tomato_bread']
['bacon', 'BREADsandwich_bread_bread__bread_']
['bacon', '_HAMsandwich__bread_ham_bread
```